# Re downloading of message when using spring integration inbound channel adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I am reading mails using spring mail inbound channel adapter once message is read i am performing some db operations in service activator of corresponding channel. My requirement is  if any db operation fails adapter should read same message again.

Mail configuration :

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel inputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pop3MailFlow() {



    String url = "[url]";
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.pop3InboundAdapter(url)
                    .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory")),e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(2000).transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())))
            .channel(inputChannel())
            .handle(inboundEmailProcessor(),"messageProcess")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public InboundEmailProcessor inboundEmailProcessor() {
    return new InboundEmailProcessor();
}

@Bean
public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
    TransactionSynchronizationFactory synchronizationFactory = new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(expressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor());
    return synchronizationFactory;
}

@Bean
public ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor expressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor processor = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    processor.setAfterRollbackExpression(parser.parseExpression("new com.muraai.ex.config.Exp().process(payload)"));
    return processor;

}

public class InboundEmailProcessor {


    @Autowired
    AttachmentsRepository attachmentsRepository;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void messageProcess() {
        // some db operations
        // if it fails the same message should be read again
    }
}
```

I thought this would work but its not working. Is there any way to achieve my requirement

```
public class Exp {

    public void process(MimeMessage message) throws MessagingException {
        message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need IMAP for that; with POP3, the server always marks them read.

You can add a spring-retry interceptor advice to the poller's advice chain and/or send the failed message to an error channel.

The retry advice can be configured for number of retries, back off policy etc.

Comment: thanks. I have changed my configuration to  IMAP  still its not working